Exercise on complex numbers (inequalities)
I am trying to do the following exercise, taken from "Complex Analysis-L. Alhfors".
I tried different approaches, for example:
$\left|\frac{a-b}{1-\bar ab}\right|<1 \iff \left|\frac{a-b}{1-\bar ab}\right|^2<1 \iff \left|a-b\right|^2<\left|1-\bar ab\right|^2\iff |a|^2+|b|^2-2Re(\bar ab)<1+|\bar ab|^2-2Re(\bar ab)\iff |a|^2+|b|^2-|a|^2|b|^2<1$, but I cannot complete the inequality.
Alternatively I tried this way:
$\left|\frac{a-b}{1-\bar ab}\right|^2=\frac{|a|^2+|b|^2-2Re(\bar ab)}{1+|\bar ab|^2-2Re(\bar ab)}=\frac{|a|^2+|b|^2-2Re(\bar ab)}{(1-Re(\bar ab))^2+Im(\bar ab)^2}\leq\frac{|a|^2+|b|^2-2Re(\bar ab)}{(1-Re(\bar ab))^2}<\frac{2}{1-Re(\bar ab)}$, but even in this way, I am not able to conclude that all this is $<1$.
How can I do it and where am I wrong?
Thanks for any suggestion and help!

Use the first approach and note that $(1-|a|^{2})(1-|b|^{2}) >0$.

@geetha290krm, thank you!

You will find systematic treatments under "Möbius transforms".
